# What is happening here in this divu with three operands?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, qtspim

I have the following line in a C code

```
i = low + (1664525*(unsigned)high + 22695477*(unsigned)low) % (high-low+1);
```

The code in MIPS that I have for this line is as follows

```
lw      $3,40($fp)
li      $2,1638400              # 0x190000
ori     $2,$2,0x660d
mult    $3,$2
mflo    $2
lw      $4,36($fp)
li      $3,22675456       # 0x15a0000
ori     $3,$3,0x4e35
mult    $4,$3
mflo    $3
addu    $2,$2,$3
lw      $4,40($fp)
lw      $3,36($fp)
nop
subu    $3,$4,$3
addiu   $3,$3,1
divu    $0,$2,$3
bne     $3,$0,1f
nop
break   7
mfhi    $2
move    $3,$2
lw      $2,36($fp)
nop
addu    $2,$3,$2
sw      $2,8($fp)
```

Here, for reference, the value of "low" is stored at 36($fp), and the value of "high" is stored at 40($fp). I am able to understand how the code is working up until this line

```
divu $0, $2, $3
```

Here, I am a bit confused about what is happening as I have only seen divu commands with two operands. Additionally, I later see that they are obtaining the mod of the division(in this line)

```
mfhi    $2
```

But, shouldn't we be getting the quotient, using "mflo" instead?
Can someone help me figure out how this part of the code is working?

Comment: `% (high-low+1)` is a remainder operation, not a `/` operator where you'd want the quotient.  As for the `$zero` destination for `divu`, that does seem odd to me but I haven't checked the manual for a while.  Normal MIPS `div` and `divu` do only take 2 operands.  http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~langer/273/12-notes.pdf

Comment: But it seems GCC uses that 3-operand form (https://godbolt.org/z/5bzjcb4nc), maybe it's just a placeholder for one of the 3 register-number fields in an R-type instruction?  But that would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

For ~current MIPS64:

According to official [MIPS manuals](https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips64/) you are looking at the assembly source for a release 6 MIPS64, which added a new instructions to deal with divide and modulo operations (DIV/MOD, DIVU/MODU, DDIV/DMOD, DDIVU/DMODU).

For example for DIVU (taken from the manual):

```
divu rd,rs,rt
```

DIVU: GPR[rd] <- sign_extend.32( divide.unsigned( GPR[rs], GPR[rt] )

DIVU performs an unsigned 32-bit integer division, and places the 32-bit quotient result in the destination register.

The 2-parameter couterparts of pre release 6 instructions now yield an reserved instruction exception

Now the interesting part:

According to the section on Availability and Compatibility from the manual "Some assemblers accept the pseudo-instruction syntax
`DIV rd,rs,rt` and expand it to do `DIV rs,rt`;`MFHI rd`. Phrases such as “DIV with GPR output” and
“DIV with HI/LO output” may be used when disambiguation is necessary."

The code you posted does use `MFLO $2` to obtain the remainder after doing the division so I believe the assembler is using MIPS64 release 6 source to target a pre release 6. The `MFHI $0` may be optimized out and now you can obtain the quotient by using `MFLO $2`

So I believe you may just see the instruction as `divu $2, $3`, with the pre release 6 HI/LO semantics

---

This was my original answer which I think make sense mostly for MIPS32 simulators:

`divu r1, r2, r3` is a pseudoinstruction. It is expanded like this in Mars:

```
  bne r3, $0, skip
  nop
  break
skip:
  divu r2, r3
  mflo r1
```

so it basically checks whether the division can be done (skips the `break` otherwise) and then performs a `divu` and gets the quotient in `r1`

As you are using `$0` as the target register it makes not much sense to use the pseudoinstruction. It will issue `mflo $0`.

You may probably just use `divu $2, $3` if you dont mind `$3` being 0

As noted in the comments, `mfhi $2` is then used to get the remainder as expected.

Comment: The OP's code looks like compiler output, specifically GCC.  (Register numbers, and the use of `0x4e35` for the `ori` immediate, but decimal for other immediates).  Thus GAS syntax not QtSPIM or MARS.  GCC does use `divu $0,$4,$5`, almost certainly not intending it as a pseudo-instruction.  Clang won't assemble that syntax.  https://godbolt.org/z/3jjaWrhvW .  This answer is useful in terms of what happens if you copy that code into MARS, though!  You get wasted instructions from the expansion of the pseudo-instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting note. Even the [manual for MIPS64] (https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips64/) does not mention `divu` with 3 parameters. We should see the machine code generated for your snippet.

Comment: Godbolt has "binary" mode for non-x86 architectures these days: https://godbolt.org/z/5c316GqKn.  (It links an executable and disassembles it with `objdump`, instead of getting asm text from the compiler without assembling.)  It is a single machine instruction, machine code `0085001b`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I looked it a bit deeper and in fact MIPS64 added/removed these instructions on release 6. I couldn't decode machine code generated for that instruction in your example back to any of the 2 flavours of DIVU though.

Comment: I'll have a look if I have time tomorrow.  `clang -target mips -c` on my desktop, and `llvm-objdump -d` also show it without using `-march=mips32r6`.  Note that MIPS32r6 and MIPS64r6 are essentially the same in opcodes supported, except for the obvious different that MIPS64 has 64-bit registers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64 (The naming change to MIPS64 instead of MIPS III / IV / V, and the existence of a 32-bit-only MIPS32 for microcontrollers that still had new instructions, was a result of MIPS Technologies (the company) being spun out of Silicon Graphics.)

Comment: double checked and the machine code generated (`0x0085001b`) does indeed correspond to `div $a0, $a1`, the pre release 6 instruction.

Comment: Thanks.  So presumably it's GNU Binutils and GCC that are just always using the new form of the instruction even when the machine code is intended for the pre-R6 meaning.  MIPS32/64 r6 rearranged some other opcodes so isn't backwards compatible in general, but in this case is binary compatible.  Existing code presumably required `0` bits in that field, and R6 can just make that mean `$zero` to have the same architectural effect as before.  But allow other things to write a useful value somewhere.

Comment: I checked what clang actually does; it's different from what MIPS manuals document.  Also, I was wrong, MIPS32r6 doesn't have LO/HI registers, and its `divu` has different machine code so it's *not* a drop-in replacement.  This is one of the opcodes that got reorganized.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at GCC output, using syntax that GAS and clang will accept.  Assembly source syntax is defined by the tool and can differ from what the vendor uses in their ISA manuals.  The manuals nail down how the binary machine-code works, but different assemblers/disassemblers can vary the syntax if they choose.

`divu $zero, src1, src2` is the GAS / clang syntax for the bare machine instruction, with implicit outputs in LO (quotient) and HI (remainder).  In MARS/SPIM, `divu srcr1, src2` is how you'd write that; MARS/SPIM and other MIPS simulators with built-in assemblers are more like classic MIPS assemblers, not the GNU toolchain.  (TODO: test what MARS accepts, and check the machine code.)

---

**With a first operand other than `$zero`, it's a destination for a pseudo-instruction.**  Clang expands it to trap on division by zero and `mflo` into the destination.  (I don't have MIPS Binutils to test with.)

For example, (keeping in mind this is clang so it's targeting real commercial MIPS with a branch-delay slot, not MARS's default of a simplified MIPS with branch delay disabled.)

```
$ clang -Wall -target mips -march=mips32r5 -O2 -c mips-div.s
$ llvm-objdump -d mips-div.o
...
00000000 <quot>:              
# divu  $v0, $4, $5 in the asm source assembled to
       0: 14 a0 00 02   bnez    $5, 12 <quot+0xc>  # skip over the break 7 on $a1!=0
       4: 00 85 00 1b   divu    $zero, $4, $5      #  in the branch-delay slot of bnez
       8: 00 07 00 0d   break   7 <quot>
       c: 00 00 10 12   mflo    $2                 # $v0
 # end of pseudocode expansion for  divu  $v0, $4, $5
...

      34: 00 85 00 1b   divu    $zero, $4, $5     # same source syntax
```

Strangely, clang at least treats `div $4, $5` as `div $4, $4, $5`, expanding it, instead of just assembling it to the bare 2-operand machine instruction.  But clang supports this as a general pattern: `addu $a0, $a1` assembles to `addu    $4, $4, $5` as if you'd written `addu $a0, $a0, $a1`.  Or as if MIPS supported a 2-operand "destructive" form that updates the destination.  So with the 2-operand syntax for `divu`, it seems this expansion takes precedence over the actual machine instruction.

Again, seems like a strange design choice for clang, or more likely for the GNU assembler many years ago. But given that fact, they did need a syntax that unambiguously indicates the bare machine instruction.  They chose a `$zero` destination.

It is an R-type instruction, and the field in the machine instruction that would normally the destination is required to be zero for `div` and `divu`.  So perhaps this makes text parsing / formatting easier in the assembler and disassembler.

The compiler knows how to lay out branches itself, and can schedule `mflo` where appropriate, so it uses the `divu $zero, src, src` version.

---

#### MIPS32/64 r6 has a 3-operand machine instruction, replacing the old

The first section of this answer is about MIPS before that, from classic MIPS I to MIPS32/64 r5.

- In MIPS32r6 / MIPS64r6, `divu` is a 3-operand instruction with a different opcode than before.  It writes the quotient to the first operand.  (LO and HI don't exist, `mflo`/`mfhi` were removed in R6.)

  ```
  # clang -target mips -march=mips32r6 div-mips.s && llvm-objdump -d div-mips.o
  00 85 00 9b   divu    $zero, $4, $5        # $a0 / $a1 discarding the result
  ```
- In earlier revisions of MIPS, `divu` is documented as a 2-operand instruction where the implicit destination is LO (quotient) and HI (remainder).  This form was removed in Release 6.

  ```
  # clang -target mips -march=mips32r5
  00 85 00 1b   divu    $zero, $4, $5     # same in the asm source
  ```

**[MIPS32/64 r6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64) in 2014 reorganized some opcodes as well as removing some rarely used ones, and is *not* binary compatible in general.**

Current versions of tools that you're using, like GCC, post-date that.  But MARS and SPIM haven't been updated for it AFAIK, and most people wouldn't want them to be unless it was an optional feature.  Typical university courses that use MIPS or a MIPS-like ISA for teaching are more like MIPS I or II from the mid to late 1980s.

But I suspect clang is just being compatible with GNU Binutils, and that it's been using the 3-operand `$zero` form to mean the bare instruction since long before 2014 when MIPS32/64 r6 was new.  But I'd be curious if anyone has MIPS Binutils, especially an old version, that could test assembling / disassembling.

See also the MIPS64r6 ISA [manual from mips.com](https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips64/).  I'm looking at [v6.06, page 194](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MD00087-2B-MIPS64BIS-AFP-6.06.pdf#page=194) from 2016 for the entry for the new form of `divu`.  (I don't expect any further updates to MIPS manuals; the ISA is commercially dead-ended.)

> **Availability and Compatibility:**
> These instructions are introduced by and required as of Release 6.
>
> Release 6 divide instructions have the same opcode *mnemonic* as the pre-Release 6 divide instructions (DIV, DIVU,
> DDIV, DDIVU). The instruction encodings are different, as are the instruction semantics: the Release 6 instruction
> produces only the quotient, whereas the pre-Release 6 instruction produces quotient and remainder in HI/LO registers
> respectively, and separate modulo instructions are required to obtain the remainder.
>
> The assembly syntax distinguishes the Release 6 from the pre-Release 6 divide instructions. For example, Release 6
> “`DIV rd,rs,rt`” specifies 3 register operands, versus pre-Release 6 “`DIV rs,rt`”, which has only two register
> arguments, with the HI/LO registers implied. Some assemblers accept the pseudo-instruction syntax
> “`DIV rd,rs,rt`” and expand it to do “`DIV rs,rt;MFHI rd`”. Phrases such as “DIV with GPR output” and
> “DIV with HI/LO output” may be used when disambiguation is necessary.

That documentation doesn't exactly match what GCC and clang do, but assembly language text source syntax is really the choice of the tool, with the vendor docs and ISA really only having full control over the rules for the machine code.

There's also a `modu` instruction on MIPS32/64 r6, which you can use instead

---

> shouldn't we be getting the quotient, using "mflo" instead?

`% (high-low+1)` is a remainder operation, not a `/` operator where you'd want the quotient.

Comment: The code used by OP has `MFHI` and `MFLO`, so it is targeting pre release 6 MIPS. I believe the reason we see the 3 parameter `DIVU` is due to what you explained about clang/gnu expanding a 2-argument instruction to a 3 argument one. Prior to release 6 there was only one variant of `DIVU` so the assembler might chose to use that format with `$0` as the first argument

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer is trying to explain, and why I put the pre-release6 section first.  If you have any ideas for getting that across more clearly on an initial skim, edits or comments welcome.  I added an explicit mention of MARS probably using different syntax, since most people reading SO questions about MIPS are learning computer architecture with a simplified-MIPS as an example (no branch delay slots), usually using MARS.